# How to convert big string values to its integer equivalent

Tags: php, mysql

I have a phone number of the format `bigint` stored in MySQL and on fetching I am getting the string equivalent of the value.

For example I am getting "919999999999" from MySQL.

How do I convert it to its integer equivalent as there is no `bigint` typecasting in php.

I have tried the following code but its not working for my value.

```
$unsignedString = "919999999999";
echo "unsigned string: ".$unsignedString."<br />";
$signedInt = intval(doubleval($unsignedString));
echo "signed int: ".$signedInt."<br />";
```

getting output `signed int: 876998655`

**Note:** Working on 64 bit Windows

Comment: Windows or Linux? 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: working on 64 bit windows

Comment: What do you currently get as output? Seems to be same here, https://3v4l.org/uWYuj

Comment: Put this in your console and hit Enter: `php -r "echo (PHP_INT_SIZE*8).' bit';"`. Whether you have 32bit or 64bit depends on what the PHP binary was compiled as.

Comment: Or... add `echo PHP_MAX_INT;` at the end of your code, and tell us what it outputs.